# Fetch an array of data and append all to another array?

Tags: php

Trial

```
//Get all id and name from db
foreach($fetchall as $all) {
       $tobeappended = array (
            'id' => $all['id'],
            'name' => $all['name']
       );
}
```

Append to

```
$myarray = array(
      //other definition here....
      'animals' => $tobeappended 
  );
```

I want to append all data from the array in foreach in the following format

```
[array('id' => '1','name'=>'cow'),array('id' => '2','name'=>'cat')]
```

Is there any way to do this

Comment: `$tobeappended[] = …` — If you want an array of arrays, build an array, not a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = [
'animals' => []
]

//Get all id and name from db
foreach($fetchall as $all) {
       $myarray['animals'][] = [
              'id' => $all['id'],
              'name' => $all['name']
           ];
       
  
}
```